# How to validate if XML matches the XSD using the xmlet / XsdParser in Java

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xml-parsing, xsd-validation

I am trying to validate if the `XML` adheres to `XSD`. To achieve this I am using [xmlet/XsdParser](https://github.com/xmlet/XsdParser) But I am unable to find any good example apart from the GitHub page.

In the readme doc, they have provided only how to convert the `XSD` to the respective `Java objects` but it does not show how to validate if the XML matches the XSD.

Following is the code that I have which reads the XSD and creates the Java Object:

```
public class XSDParser {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {
        String xsdPath = Paths.get(XSDParser.class.getClassLoader().getResource("test.xsd").toURI()).toFile().getAbsolutePath();
        String filePath = Path.of(xsdPath).toString();
        XsdParser parserInstance = new XsdParser(filePath);
        System.out.println(filePath);
        Stream<XsdElement> elementsStream = parserInstance.getResultXsdElements();
        Stream<XsdSchema> schemasStream = parserInstance.getResultXsdSchemas();

    }
}
```

This code reads the XSD file and creates the Stream of the element. Now I have also added the following lines of the code which will read the XML file and create the stream:

```
String absolutePath = Paths.get(ApplicationMain.class.getClassLoader().getResource("inputXML.xml").toURI()).toFile()
                            .getAbsolutePath();
        String path = Path.of(absolutePath).toString();
        File xml = new File(path);
        InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(xml);
```

Now, I want to know if my XML adheres to the XSD that I have read and stored. How to achieve this?

1. I would like to use the `XMLET/XSDPARSER` to parse my XSD file.
2. I am using the `SAX PARSER` to parse my XML file.
3. I am unable to find any good example on the net which has been implemented using the `XMLET/XSDPARSER`.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The library you're using is apparently a library for analysing XSD schemas, not for using the schema for validation, so you're using the wrong tool for the job. You can perform XSD 1.0 validation in Java using the JAXP interfaces (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/validating.html), and if you want to use XSD 1.1, download Apache Xerces or Saxon.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually, I am trying to convert the XML to JSON. While converting to JSON I would like to know what type of object each element can take. I would like to use `xmlet/XsdParser` to check that so I can accordingly create either `Object` or `Array` within my JSON. I am guessing that possible to do using the library. But I cannot find any example for that anywhere in google. If possible can you please let me know how to verify the type of objects available for the XML in XSD using the `xmlet/XsdParser `? Even a basic example with few tags would work for me.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the `xmlet` library. If I were doing this I would use a schema-aware XSLT transformation in Saxon which gives you XSD type annotations on each node of the instance document, and then use these type annotations to control further processing.

Comment: Sure, thanks a lot for your response. I will try the XSDParser if that does not workout then I will go for the SAX as you mentioned.

Comment: I have a doubt regarding the XSD parsing hope you can help: As I mentioned earlier I would like to know the data type of every element that I encounter in the XML file from the XSD file so I am looking for an efficient and best library. I came across `SAXON` and `XERCES2`. I wanted to know which will be a better choice?

Comment: As the author of Saxon, I will naturally recommend that as the better choice. But you're not supposed to ask for advice on product selection on StackOverflow.